# What Introductory Statistics book would you recommend?

Tags: statistics, books

Is there a particularly good book or good publisher for teaching Statistics from beginner level for someone interested in studying Data Science?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), by Trevor Hastie and Rob Tibshirani. That link gets the book directly from their Stanford website.

In addition, [there are also accompanying videos](https://www.r-bloggers.com/in-depth-introduction-to-machine-learning-in-15-hours-of-expert-videos/) (they follow the structure of a similar book), which are really helpful!

They offer a simpler set of books and online courses, which [you can find listed here.](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/lectures.htm)